# SOAP Envelope is dropped when sending message out in WSO2

Tags: xml, soap, wso2, payload, wso2-micro-integrator

I am trying to build a SOAP message with a proper envelope then body but I am unable to get it. Below are the lines of code I am writing to build it.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soapenv:Body>
                <prov>
                    <abc>123456</abc>
                    <xyz>789</xyz>
                </prov>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </format>
    <args/>
</payloadFactory>
<property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
<property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
<call>
    <endpoint key="ActiveMQ_EP"/>
</call>
<respond/>
```

The result I am getting is as follows:

```
<prov xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <abc>123456</abc>
    <xyz>789</xyz>
</prov>
```

There isn't proper SOAP payload with Envelope then body and then prov instead its starting with prov. Any help in this matter would be very helpful.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the following property before sending the message out.

```xml
<property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
```

**Update**

Try forcing soap1.1 message with `format="soap11"` flag in your endpoint configuration. This will work with both HTTP and Address Endpoints.

```xml
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <http method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:81/post" format="soap11"> 
            <suspendOnFailure>
                <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
            </suspendOnFailure>
            <markForSuspension>
                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            </markForSuspension>
        </http>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```

If you are ok with SOAP 1.2 messages you can also try adding the following message type.

```xml
<property name="messageType" value="application/soap+xml" scope="axis2"/>
```

But for SOAP 1.2 you may have to alter the Payload accordingly.

Comment: can you please check if this is the change you were saying. Incase yes then its still give the same output, as stated in the question. Please let me know if something is wrong. I have edited the question. Thanks